# T-SQL query to find all user IDs that worked all specified dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table designed like this (simple example):

`WorkRecords` (UserID, DateWorked)

```
UserID        DateWorked    
-----------   -----------------   
111111        '2023/09/01'
222222        '2023/09/01'
333333        '2023/09/02'
222222        '2023/09/02'
111111        '2023/09/02'
333333        '2023/09/01'
111111        '2023/09/03'
```

I need to query the table and return the `UserID`s of every person that worked all specified dates (in real usage I am querying over a 20-day date range). In this example if I wanted to know the ID of who worked 9/1 and 9/2 and 9/3 (user 111111), what is the most efficient way to do so?

Possibly an easy way, but it eludes me. The current way I am doing it is using a CTE of each date and doing multiple UNIONs but it's an extremely taxing query.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using queries with a GROUP BY and HAVING clause to filter the results based on the specified dates. for example:

```
SELECT UserID    
FROM WorkRecords    
WHERE DateWorked IN ('2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03')    
GROUP BY UserID    
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DateWorked) = 3; -- Adjust the count based on the number of dates you're checking
```

Comment: This appears to work. Doing further testing. Knew some SQL guru would be able to do it in a heartbeat. Thanks and I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: Thanks much Carlos! I'd name my next child after you, but I was neutered many years ago.

Comment: You are welcome! hehe I'm glad it works for you, greetings